# I'm using navigation to navigate my react native app and I couldn't Paypass this issue. I did as the docs but nothing works for me

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The problem is I'm trying to use the navigation option to add a header and right button to navigate me to another screen, but it keeps giving me this error: "navigation.navigate is not a function. (in navigation.navigate is undefined)

Here is my code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import{View,Text, Button} from 'react-native'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';





function HomeScreen(navigation) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="button"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen')}></Button>
    </View>
  );
}


function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Homes" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the definition of HomeScreen component

```
function HomeScreen(navigation)
```

To:

```
function HomeScreen({navigation})
```